# Laravel application running war file like tomcat

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tomcat, war

I have a laravel application, and a war file. Both run like expected, but separately.
Laravel in vagrant/homestead and the war file with tomcat.

My objective is to run the war file within the laravel application. I haven't found anyone doing something like this.

I tried extracting the content of the war file but I get some errors, from missing files that I can't find anywhere.

Has anyone a clue on how to do this / an example I can follow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The answer below follows the tag's descriptions for [war](/questions/tagged/war) files as

> Web Application Archive - Is Jar file used to distribute JavaServer Pages, Java Servlets, Java classes, XML files, tag libraries and static Web pages (HTML and related files) that together constitute a Web application.

But, according to the comments, it seems that PHP can be packaged in WAR files as well. With that aspect, my answer won't be helpful (sorry), but I'll leave it here in case someone actually later on finds this question for a mixed Java/PHP environment:

---

According to the tag descriptions:

> [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) is a free, open-source PHP web framework, created by Taylor Otwell and intended for the development of web applications following the model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern and based on Symfony.

and

> [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) is an open source Servlet Container

E.g. tomcat is more an application server, while Laravel is a library. Good luck running something (written in Java) within a PHP environment. (e.g. it won't work)

What you can do is to run tomcat, and serve its files from the same webserver that you serve your Laravel application from (e.g. Apache httpd, nginx). You'll have to lookup "reverse proxy" for it, e.g. "mount" a certain part of the URL hierarchy from Tomcat to your Webserver.

But to run any Java code and JSPs within a PHP environment? No.

Comment: I understend that, so what would you recommend me to use so that I can run my x-text dsl + ace/orion on laravel? Becase I need to be able to run an x-text project in laravel, if this makes sense

Comment: As you mentioned and tagged Tomcat, I'm assuming that you're running a Java WAR file, together with your Laravel application - or does Laravel also deploy code within WAR files? I only know them from the Java world, and that's the perspective that my answer is written from. If this is also a thing in the PHP world, then I'm wrong and probably will delete. If you're referring to a Java-WARfile, this makes sense. But with this comment I'm confused (which is due to my missing PHP background, less your question/comment)

Comment: Yes It is a java war file I got from eclipse x-text, and a php framework, laravel, I think you understood it right.
And I have to use my war file in my web app, I managed to get most of it working by extracting but I keep getting some files missing

Comment: With PHP packaged in war files, I'm afraid, I'm out. See my edit to the answer - I'm coming from the Java world and won't be able to help you on any PHP packaging format and what's included.

Comment: I think you got it wrong here, the war file I'm talking about is exactly that one, my war file contains some folders, an index.html and some javascript

Comment: I can run my war file without any problem using tomcat